# Laravel. Replacing objects with stubs in a DI container does not work during tests

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-6

Using Laravel 6.

I am writing a unit test for a single factory class that creates objects depending on which argument is passed. Objects are created through a DI container.

```
public function make(string $general_group, array $data): SubmissionInterface
{
    switch ($general_group) {
        case Transaction::getAlnGeneralGroup():
            return $this->build(AlnSubmission::class, $data);
        case Transaction::getAtmGeneralGroup():
            return $this->build(AtmSubmission::class, $data);
        case Transaction::getPosGeneralGroup():
            return $this->build(PosSubmission::class, $data);
        case Transaction::getCharityGeneralGroup():
            return $this->build(HlpSubmission::class, $data);
        case Transaction::getRecGeneralGroup():
            return $this->build(RecSubmission::class, $data);
        case Transaction::getPartialPaymentGeneralGroup():
            return $this->build(OchSubmission::class, $data);
        case Transaction::getSstGeneralGroup():
            return $this->build(SstSubmission::class, $data);
        default:
            throw new UnexpectedValueException("Unknown general group");
    }
}

private function build(string $class, array $data)
{
    return App::makeWith(
        $class,
        [
            'request' => $data,
            'transaction_facade' => $this->transaction_facade,
            'client_service' => $this->client_service,
            'construct_cache_key_factory' => $this->construct_cache_key_factory,
        ]
    );
}
```

In tests, code is written like this:

```
public function testReturnSubmission()
{
    $this->changeOutputObjectInContainer(AlnSubmission::class);

    $submission = $this->submission_factory->make('ALN', []);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(AlnSubmission::class, $submission);
}

private function changeOutputObjectInContainer(string $class)
{
    $mock = $this->createMock($class);
    $this->app->instance($class, $mock);
}
```

And when replacing an object through the "instance" method, the container issues the old object, not a stub. In this case, if you specify the code like this, then I will get a stub.

```
public function testReturnSubmission()
{
    $this->changeOutputObjectInContainer(AlnSubmission::class);

    $a = $this->app->make(AlnSubmission::class);

    // $submission = $this->submission_factory->make('ALN', []);
    // $this->assertInstanceOf(AlnSubmission::class, $submission);
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved with a plug on the facade

```
private function changeOutputObjectInContainer(string $class)
{
    $mock = $this->createMock($class);
    App::shouldReceive('makeWith')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn($mock);
}
```